# Makefile extract part of filepath as compiler flag

Tags: makefile

as i am currently working on my makefile i encountered another problem. I am using this rule as part of my building process which transforms .mid files into .s files.

```
$(MIDAS): $(BLDPATH)/%.s: %.mid
$(shell mkdir -p $(dir $@))
#test $($< | sed "*")
$(MID2AGB) $(MIDFLAGS) -G$($< | sed ".*mus/vcg([0-9]{3})/.*\.mid") $< $@
```

All .mid input files follow the same format: .*mus/vcg[0-9]{3}/.*.mid, meaning they are stored in different directories following the naming convention vcgXXX where X can be any digit from 0-9. (Maybe my regex is even wrong for this).
When i am calling $(MID2AGB) i want to use a compiler flag -GXXX. However the XXX of this flag has to match the XXX from the input file path.

My makefile code does not work. Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a crude but effective way to do this using Make's string manipulation tools:

```
# suppose the source is .mus/vcg456/Z.mid

$(MIDAS): $(BLDPATH)/%.s: %.mid
    @echo $*                                     # this gives .mus/vcg456/Z
    @echo $(subst /, ,$*)                        # this gives .mus vcg456 Z
    @echo $(word 2,$(subst /, ,$*)               # this gives vcg456
    @echo $(subst vcg,,$(word 2,$(subst /, ,$*)) # this gives 456
```